# what does an "expression" in C language mean?

Tags: c

I have been involved in C programming for quite some time now.
A few days back, I stumbled upon a wrongly written code, which let me to the following question.

What would the following C code print out.

```
if (0,2)  
    printf("red");
```

Comment: Why do you not just run your code? http://ideone.com/4bWmN

Comment: @halex Just running it won't tell you what's up if undefined (or merely unspecified or even implementation-defined) behaviour is involved.

Comment: In simple terms, an expression is a set of operators, constants, numbers, and values that boil down to a value of some kind.  `1`, `NULL`, `6*5`, `a=0`, and yes, `0,2` are expressions.  `break`, `return`, and `for` are not -- they have no value.

Comment: How is the title connected to the question?

Answer (score 9):

The output of the code will be:

```
red
```

The condition for the `if` statement employs the *comma operator*, which evaluates to the result of the second operand, in this case: *2*. Since non-zero in C is analogous to *true*, the expression is *true*, and the `printf` executes.

Using the comma operator, the first operand is evaluated and the result is discarded, then the second operand is evaluated, and the result and type of the expression is the result and type of the evaluation of this second operand. Read more about the comma operator [at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Answer (score 5):

It [would print `red`](http://ideone.com/FJwPH), unlike

```
if (2,0)
    printf("red")
```

which would print nothing.

This is the way [the comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) in C works -- it evaluates its operands one by one, and produces the result of the last one as its overall result.

Answer (score 1):

In a `if` statement, the statement is executed if the controlling expression is different than zero.

`0, 2` is a comma expression and it evaluates to the right operand `2` which is different than zero.

So the statement in the `if` expression:

```
printf("red");
```

will be executed in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator, in the context you gave, is useless.

```
if (0,2)
   printf("red");
```

In this case it says:

```
Do nothing with 0
if (2)  //which is true
print "red"
```

Basically it does nothing for you unless you want the opp(s) before the last value to have meaning. A **slightly** more useful example of why you'd want this:

```
int i, j;
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
for(i=0, j=1; i<4; j+=2, i+=2){
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", j, arr[j]);
}
```

Now with only 2 iterations of this loop we're printing out all 4 values in the array:

```
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 4
```

It works the same with more than two operations in there as well, so if you wanted you could do:

```
if(a++, b++, 1)
  printf("red");
```

Now you'll get a and b incremented while printing "red"

Answer (score 0):

It would print `red` , because the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates first operand and discard result, then evaluates second operand and returns result, so it returns `2` which is a `TRUE` value and so enters the IF block.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title (from the [C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

> #### 6.5 Expressions
>
> 1 An *expression* is a sequence of operators and operands that speciﬁes computation of a
> value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that
> performs a combination thereof. The value computations of the operands of an operator
> are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.

In the snippet

```
if (0,2)
    printf("red");
```

`0,2` is a *comma expression*; each of the subexpressions `0` and `2` are evaluated from left-to-right, and the value of the comma expression is the value of the rightmost subexpression (in this case, `2`).  Since the result of `0,2` is non-zero, the branch is taken and the `printf` statement is executed.

Note that the comma operator is different from the comma used to separate arguments in a function:

```
foo(a, b, c);
```

In this case, `a, b, c` is a *parameter list*, not a comma expression.  There's no specific order of evaluation (`c` may be evaluated before `a` or `b`) and no resulting value.